# How to convert Camel Case to Lower Hyphen in Java when there are contiguous capitals

Tags: java, regex, guava

I have the string "B2BNewQuoteProcess". When I use Guava to convert from Camel Case to Lower Hyphen as follows:

```
CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_HYPHEN,"B2BNewQuoteProcess");
```

I get "b2-b-new-quote-process".

What I am looking for is "b2b-new-quote-process"...

How do I do this in Java?

Comment: Use `(?=[A-Z][a-z])` replace with `-` and then convert string to lowercase

Comment: Works great! Thx!

Comment: I've converted my comment above to an answer

Comment: Note that your original string is not upper camel, unless you accept that the second "B" is a separate word. In order to be consistent, you'd have to use `B2bNewQuoteProcess` (which looks a bit ugly).

Answer (score 11):

## Edit

To prevent `-` at the beginning of a line, use the following instead of my original answer:

```
(?!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])
```

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/KL8yVp/1)

```
(?=[A-Z][a-z])
```

Replacement: `-`

**Note**: The regex above doesn't convert the uppercase characters to lowercase; it simply inserts `-` into the positions that should have them. The conversion of uppercase characters to lowercase character occurs in the Java code below using `.toLowerCase()`.

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/3MIQ5P)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final String regex = "(?=[A-Z][a-z])";
        final String string = "B2BNewQuoteProcess";
        final String subst = "-";
        
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        
        // The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
        final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);
        
        System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?=[A-Z][a-z])` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is an uppercase ASCII letter followed by a lowercase ASCII letter. This is used as an assertion for the position. The replacement simply inserts a hyphen `-` into the positions that match this lookahead.

Comment: @MariusSoutier you’re correct, I’ve edited my answer to include a fix for this case

Answer (score 1):

**METHOD FOR VERSIONS BELOW JAVA 8**

Use this method to convert any camel case string. You can select any type of separator.

```
private String camelCaseToLowerHyphen(String s) {
    StringBuilder parsedString = new StringBuilder(s.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase());
    for (char c : s.substring(1).toCharArray()) {
      if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        parsedString.append("_").append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
      } else {
        parsedString.append(c);
      }
    }
    return parsedString.toString().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Original code taken from: http://www.java2s.com/example/java-utility-method/string-camel-to-hyphen-index-0.html

Answer (score 1):

| Camel case | Lower hyphen | Should have been |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B2BNewQuoteProcess | b2-b-new-quote-process | b2b-new-quote-process |
| BaBNewQuoteProcess | ba-b-new-quote-process |  |
| B2NewQuoteProcess | b2-new-quote-process |  |
| BABNewQuoteProcess | b-a-b-new-quote-process | bab-new-quote-process |

So:

- Digits after a capital count as capital too
- With N+1 "capitals" the first N capitals form a word

A repair of the wrong result would be:

```
String expr = "b2-b-new-quote-process";
expr = Pattern.compile("\\b[a-z]\\d*(-[a-z]\\d*)+\\b")
    .matcher(expr).replaceAll(mr ->
        mr.group().replace("-", ""));
```

This searches between word boundaries (`\b`) a sequence of letter with any digits, followed by a repetition of hyphen plus letter with any digits.